# How to split a column in a dataframe and store each value as a new row (in pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas

One of the columns in my dataset has "keywords" values stored like this:

```
monster|dna|tyrannosaurus rex|velociraptor|island
```

I want to split each keyword on (|) *the pipeline* and store it as a new row, so I can later use *groupby* to look at correlations based on the keywords.

The furthest I got was:

```
dfn = df['keywords'].str.split('|',expand=True)
```

But this stores them as new columns, not new rows, and this only stores these values only in a new dataframe. I still need to .append it back into the original dataframe, and then drop the original rows containing keyword clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adding `stack` after `split`

```
dfn = df['keywords'].str.split('|',expand=True).stack()
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, might you know how I would append this back into the original dataframe? I'm getting a `Expected tuple, got str` error.

Comment: @bytebybyte but the shape of this serise is not same with your df , you can look at pd.concate

Comment: Is there a better approach to breaking each keyword out and re-inserting each keyword back into the DataFrame while retaining all of the original values? so if keyword cluster has "monkeys|bananas" and revenue is "2m", there would be a row "monkeys" with "2m" and a 2nd row "bananas" with "2m".

Comment: `df.set_index('revenue ')['keywords'].str.split('|',expand=True).stack().reset_index()` @bytebybyte check this

Comment: thanks! This is close to working: `0 Jurassic World 0 monster
1 Jurassic World 1 dna
2 Jurassic World 2 tyrannosaurus rex
3 Jurassic World 3 velociraptor
4 Jurassic World 4 island`  - but there are about 7 other columns I'd want to retain as well. I looked at documentation for .reset_index but it looks like that only lets me pick 1 option

Comment: nevermind, used `dfn = df.merge(rev, left_on='id', right_on='id', how='inner')` to merge the new one using your use of `set_index, stack() and reset_index` -- this works great. Thanks again!